# Why do I have to run npm rebuild node-sass --force after every time I do a `yarn add`?

Tags: javascript, npm, yarnpkg

I'm trying to install the `isemail` npm library. The install seems to go well but when I run `yarn start:dev`, which is a shortcut for `"npm run build:dev && ./scripts/gendevconfig.sh && cross-env BABEL_DISABLE_CACHE=1 NODE_ENV=development node server/server.js",`

I get a bunch of node-sass errors that all recommend the same step:

> run: npm rebuild node-sass --force

I'd like to not have to do this step every time I install a new package via yarn. Any ideas on how to rectify this?

Thanks!

Comment: check versions. this seems like quite old and resolved issue. https://github.com/sass/node-sass/issues/1918

Comment: node-sass 4.14.1 rebuilds every `yarn` run. Is it too old and where should I update? They just want fix it..

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
yarn install --force
```

Work for me.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Please consider giving some explanation why the problem is occurring and how your answer solves it.

Answer (score 0):

This problem happens usually because of incompatibility of node version with node-Sass.

Comment: Shouldn't it be a comment?

Comment: I wanted to keep that as a standalone answer because I expect many experiments will be added to this answer, like what Node Engine works with Node-Sass. so just wanted to start the research.